# How to join two large tables with different strings

Tags: php, mysql, sql, indexing

I have two tables

```
table1
customer_id 
101
102
103
```

and table2

```
customer_id country_id 
  AO-101      1
  AO-102      2    
  AO-103      3
```

both the tables are very large tables I have used `CONCAT(table1.customer_id)` for joining with the table2

all the fields stated above are index fields

joining them and getting all the customer of country 1 is taking lot of time

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Simple. Normalise your design. If customer_id is 102 in one table, then it should be 102 in the other table too.

Comment: Agree with @Strawberry, consistency is important.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this mate:

```
SELECT * FROM table1  
JOIN table2 ON CONCAT('AO-', table1.customer_id) = table2.customer_id  
WHERE table2.country_id = 1;
```

or this one:

```
SELECT * FROM table2
JOIN (
    SELECT CONCAT('AO-', customer_id) AS in_customer_id, table1.* FROM table1
) AS table1 ON table1.in_customer_id = table2.customer_id
WHERE table2.country_id = 1;
```

Comment: This (like all the other 'answers' thus far provided) cannot use an index, so despite the healthy number of upvotes, it's still going to be painfully slow.

Comment: I think maybe because of the design and implementation of records in both tables. IMHO

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem you are running into is HOW an index is stored.

The way to understand this is to literally think of a PHYSICAL index that sits NEXT to the table as alookup.

If you do something like `"create index index_1 on table1(column_1)"`, what this is does is stores this right next to the table and before you run a query referencing that table, the the DBMS looks over the tables and your query and determines the best way to query the tables based on indexes, table sizes, etc.

Now, the index stores literally the exact value in the exact DATATYPE as the field, unless you cast the index as a different datatype.

Right now you are joining an integer field to a character field and right there, you are not going to get the same performance from the index as you cannot use the index purely as such - it has to be translated on the fly, so to speak.

So what I would do is type something like:

```
create index on table2(cast(replace(customer_id,'AO-','') as integer));
```

This should store an integer value as the INDEX so when joined to the integer primary key, the index should run fine.

Also, why don't you just store the same integer value instead of adding this 'AO-' thing?

Answer (score 0):

mysql uses `CONCAT()` to concatenate strings

So we use following query:

```
ON tableTwo.query = concat('category_id=',tableOne.category_id)
```

Hope this helps to you.

Comment: i did'nt understant your answer  please can you add a little more explanation i need to get all the customer_id for country_id = 1

Answer (score 0):

You can write a subquery like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN 
    (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(customer_id, '-', -1) AS customer_id, country_id
            FROM table2) t2 USING customer_id;
```

I haven't tried it, but you might also be able to join directly:

```
ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(table2.customer_id, '-', -1) = table1.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code It's Working.**

select * from table4 t4, table3 t3 where t4.cus_id in (CONCAT('A0-', t3.cus_id)) &&  t4.country=1 ;